# Simple spreadsheet formatting automation - adding rows and splitting or merging with drop down selection

Tags: excel, vba

I usually can get what I need for built-in features from Google. Not the case here. I can't find a way to do this. I don't mind doing this with a macro if needed. I would appreciate some advice on how to do it. I can easily make a drop down menu for the number of rows I want to have for each PO (purchase order), but having excel add them and merge the added cells left of the selection into the original row automatically seems to not be a popular thing to attempt.

[image: Invoice tracking spreadsheet]

This image should show the desired functionality. If I was going to try to write a command or operation based macro, it would do this (not correct syntax, I don't know these commands yet):

```
User input equals N (1 to 10) into row X
Add (N-1) rows below row X
Merge column A, row (X:X+N-1)
Merge column B, row (X:X+N-1)
Merge column C, row (X:X+N-1)
```

That would be it. I would prefer to not have the user have to click a button (other than using the drop down menu) to accomplish this. If it is done with a macro, I Would also add the following logic (not in correct syntax, but you get the idea):

If the user has typed data into added rows in comumns D or E and tries to change their "SPLIT #" selection and delete rows that have said data, it will not let them do so until the data is deleted. This would be an effort to prevent accidental data deletion.

I hope this makes sense. I am trying to track purchase orders at a small company and it is getting REALLY messy when suppliers ship partials on purchase orders. Sometimes there are orders split into 4 or 5 shipments...

I am trying to get this to work. It just loops forever.

```
Sub options() 
    '**** Define variables ****' 
    Dim lRow As Long 
    Dim lRsp As Long 
    Dim i As Long 
    Dim n As Long 
    
    n = ActiveCell.Value 
    MsgBox "The value of n is " & i, vbInformation
    
    On Error Resume Next
    lRow = Selection.Row()
    lRsp = MsgBox("Insert New row above " & lRow & "?", _
            vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
    If lRsp <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

    For i = 1 To 4
        Rows(lRow).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Rows(lRow + 1).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Rows(lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: what happens if the user selects 4 then selects 3 for the same cell?  do you expect 7 rows. 3 rows, 4 rows?  What do you want to happen if there is information in a row and the user changes the value?  Does it get deleted?  It's easy to just add rows based on a user selection...it's a lot harder to sort out if the user makes a change to that dropdown.

Comment: First of all you need to remove `On Error Resume Next` tihs line is toxic as it hides **all** error messages, but the errors still occur, you just cannot see their messages. If you don't see them you cannot fix them, if you don't fix them your code cannot work. So remove that line and fix your errors (or tell us which one you get). • Also this loop cannot run forever it can only run 4 times (unless you run it from a worksheet_change event, if so please show the code of that event too).

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole lot of ways to achieve what you're after, but here is one way:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C10")) Is Nothing And Target.Value <> "" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("A" & Target.Row + 1 & ":G" & Target.Row + Target.Value).Insert
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Obviously adjust the ranges to suit your sheet, but this should get you started.  One thing to keep in mind.  If you keep changing values in column "C", you will continually add rows.  You'll have to work out how you want to handle those changes.